# Using AutoMapper to update property on owned entity doesn't set it as Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

Tried posting this as an issue on AutoMapper's GitHub but it was insta-closed and pointed here.

In EF Core 3.1, using AutoMapper to update an entity with an owned type does not trigger EF Core's change detection.

This issue was not present in EF Core 2.2.

#### Source/destination types

```
public class SomeOwnedType
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SomeOwnedType Something { get; set; } = new SomeOwnedType();
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
public class SomeEntityForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SomeOwnedType Something { get; set; } = new SomeOwnedType();
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<...>
{
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> Entities { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) =>
        builder.Entity<SomeEntity>().OwnsOne(e => e.Something);
}
```

#### Mapping configuration

```
CreateMap<SomeEntity, SomeEntityForm>()
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UpdatedAt, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Something, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue());

CreateMap<SomeOwnedType, SomeOwnedType>();
```

#### Version: 9.0.0 on EF Core 3.1

AutoMapper Collection 5.0.0

AutoMapper Extensions Microsoft DependencyInjection 7.0.0

#### Expected behavior

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SomeAction([FromForm] SomeEntityForm form)
{
    var entity = await context.Entities.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        mapper.Map(form, entity);
        entity.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;

        context.Entities.Update(entity);

        var changes = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        // entity -> Modified
        // entity.Something -> Modified

        return Ok();
    }

    return BadRequest();
}
```

#### Actual behavior

```
var form = ...; // Something.SomeString = "qwerty"
var entity = ...; // Something.SomeString = "abcde"

mapper.Map(form, entity);
// entity.Something.SomeString = "qwerty"

context.Entities.Update(entity);

var changes = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
// entity -> Modified
// no entry for entity.Something
```

#### Steps to reproduce

As above in `Expected behaviour`.

Incidentally, manually modifying the field marks the expected entities as modified:

```
var entity = ...; // Something.SomeString = "qwerty"

entity.Something.SomeString = "abcde";

context.Entities.Update(entity);

var changes = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
// entity -> Modified
// entity.Something -> Modified
```

Oddly enough, this issue does not occur in a cleanly spun up .NET Core 3.1 project, but only appears in an upgraded project previously on .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: In EF Core 3, owned types can now be null if they don't have any required fields. Has automapper been updated to account for this semantic change?

Comment: Are you asking if AutoMapper itself has been updated? From what I can tell, there should be no need, as inspecting the execution plan shows it will handle `null` owned entities.
If you meant that I should update my AutoMapper configuration, what can you see that I've missed?

Comment: Where is the PK of `SomeEntity`? And is it included in `SomeEntityForm`? Please update the code in the post so the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Updated with primary key fields. Not having the `Id` in the form doesn't affect the mapping.

Comment: In my tests it does matter. Also, regarding `var entity = …;` - are you retrieving the entity from the context and using tracking query, i.e. is the entity attached to the context? Please include full reproducible example, with EF Core every detail matters.

Comment: Updated with more info.

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" to this problem was to:

- Use a migration to create another owned property on the parent of the same type
- Use another migration to copy the data from the original columns into the new
- Use another migration to drop the old columns
- Use another migration to rename the new columns to the old

It's terrible and far from ideal, but it works and I have no further issues.

EDIT: with further tinkering, I think it has to do with nullable owned entities and how tracking works when a new instance of one is added to the parent.